# ¿En qué entorno evalúa `stat_smooth()` la función que ajusta el modelo?

Tags: r, ggplot2

tratando de responder [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/155001/gr%C3%A1ficar-juntos-varios-nls-y-un-lm) me compliqué con `ggplot()`, `geom_smooth()` y creo que con los entornos de evaluación de las funciones.

Publiqué la pregunta en [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49820898/how-to-plot-multiple-nls-fit-curves-with-geom-smooth-getting-model-parame), sin respuesta aún. Para eso cree un reprex más simple que acá les presento. El problema es el que surgió en la pregunta de formulada en este foro.

Lo que busco es graficar cinco curvas resultantes de cinco modelos aplicados cada uno a un subconjunto de datos de una variable. El tipo de modelo que ajusto requiere que le pasemos una lista de parámetros de inicio. En este caso son específicos para cada subconjunto, el `min()` de una variable y el `max()` de otra.

Con `geom_smooth()` y `aes(..., color = variable_que_organiza_los_subconjuntos`) debería ser fácil y lo es, siempre que conozca de antemano los parámetros de inicio para el modelo `nls`.

## 1. Parámetros fijos conocidos. (No es lo que quiero)

```
library(tidyverse)
msleep %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = sleep_rem, y = sleep_total, color = vore)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "nls", 
              se = FALSE, 
              formula = y ~ max_sleep_total * x / (min_sleep_rem + x),
              method.args = list(start = list(max_sleep_total = 19.9,   #Le paso parámetros fijos para el modelo.
                                              min_sleep_rem   = 1.88)))  
#Emite un waring por unos missing, no creo que sea el problema.
```

Busqué varias maneras de que `ggplot()` -o `stat_smooth()`, no sé exactamente cómo funciona como se las arreglan internamente- calculen los parámetros de inicio durante la ejecución y que lo hagan para cada subconjunto de datos. En principio lo obvio sería usar los nombres internos definidos en aes()`. De hecho así se los paso a la fórmula del modelo.

## 2. Nombres de las variables asignados en `aes()`.  No funciona.

```
msleep %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = sleep_rem, y = sleep_total, color = vore)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "nls", 
              se = FALSE, 
              formula = y ~ max_sleep_total * x / (min_sleep_rem + x),     #Acá y = sleep_total
              method.args = list(start = list(max_sleep_total = max(y),    #Acá... NO. 
                                              min_sleep_rem   = min(x))))
# Mensaje de error: 

#Error in geom_smooth(method = "nls", se = FALSE, formula = y ~ max_sleep_total *  : 
#  objeto 'y' no encontrado
```

## 3. Nombres de columna de los datos. Tampoco.

```
msleep %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = sleep_rem, y = sleep_total, color = vore)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "nlsLM", 
              se = FALSE, 
              formula = y ~ max_sleep_total * x / (min_sleep_rem + x),
              method.args = list(start = list(max_sleep_total = max(sleep_total), 
                                              min_sleep_rem   = min(sleep_rem))))
```

Mismo error que en anterior, sólo cambia el nombre de objeto perdido.

```
#Error in geom_smooth(method = "nlsLM", se = FALSE, formula = y ~ max_sleep_total *  : 
#  objeto 'sleep_total' no encontrado
```

## 4. ¿En el entorno global? Sí.

```
max_sleep_total <-c(0, 19.9)  # Asigno al entorno global 
min_sleep_rem <- c(1.88, 10)  # Pongo dos valores para ver si min y max funcionan.

msleep %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = sleep_rem, y = sleep_total, color = vore)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "nls", 
              se = FALSE, 
              formula = y ~ max_sleep_total * x / (min_sleep_rem + x),
              method.args = list(start = list(max_sleep_total = max(max_sleep_total), 
                                              min_sleep_rem   = min(min_sleep_rem)))) + 
  labs(title = "Code block 4")
```

Sale este gráfico, el mismo que obtenía con la opción 1. No es el que busco.

[image]

## Pregunta:

- ¿Alguien entiende por qué `ggplot()` en algunos casos evalúa en un entorno y en otros casos en otro, sin motivo aparente?
- ¿Hay alguna forma de explicitar el entorno de evaluación dentro de `stat_smooth()`?

  - Si se puede ¿qué entorno sería el que tengo que usar?
- Revisando el código de `stat_smooth` encuentro que la línea en la que ejecuta el modelo antes de graficar hace usa un `do.call`, al que le pasa la función y una lista de argumentos. (Línea 133 de https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-smooth.r )

  - ¿Tendrá eso algo que ver?
  - La ayuda de `do.call()`  dice:

> ```
> Usage:
>
> do.call(what, args, quote = FALSE, envir = parent.frame())
> ```

- ¿Esto es un problema de entornos de evaluación o estoy buscando una solución en el lugar equivocado?

> No estoy interesado en workarounds para sacar el gráfico por otras vías. Se puede, no es el punto de la pregunta. Es sólo una manera de ejemplificar el problema.

Gracias de antemano!

## Referencias:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030653/fitting-with-ggplot2-geom-smooth-and-nls

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45971661/how-to-use-method-nlslm-in-packages-minpack-lm-in-geom-smooth

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106782/use-of-ggplot-within-another-function-in-r

## Actualización:

Con la pregunta respondida incluyo una forma muy ad hoc de resolver el problema. Consiste en ajustar primero los modelos usando `map`, que permite referir directamente a los nombres de los datos en una función dentro de la lista `start=`. Luego predecir en base a cada modelo con una secuencia larga de puntos para que las curvas salgan bien y finalmente hacer el gráfico con dos series de datos: la original y los puntos predichos. 
Es un código medio feo y complicado de reutilizar, ya que habría que cambiar muchos nombres y afinar la secuencia de `newdata=` en cada caso. Pero [funciona](https://xkcd.com/1695/).

```
msleep %>% 
  split(.$vore) %>% 
  map(~nls(formula = sleep_total ~ max_sleep_total * sleep_rem / (min_sleep_rem + sleep_rem), 
           start = list(max_sleep_total = max(.$sleep_total, na.rm = TRUE), 
                        min_sleep_rem   = min(.$sleep_rem, na.rm = TRUE)),
           data = .))  %>% 
  map_df(~predict(., 
         newdata = list(sleep_rem = seq(0, max(msleep$sleep_rem, na.rm = T), by=.25)))) %>% 
  mutate(sleep_rem = seq(0, max(msleep$sleep_rem, na.rm = T), by=.25)) %>% 
  gather(vore, .fitted, -sleep_rem) -> 
  predichos

ggplot(msleep, aes(x = sleep_rem, y= sleep_total, color = vore)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(data = predichos, aes(x = sleep_rem, 
                                  y = .fitted, 
                                  color = vore, 
                                  group = vore))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La cuestión,  no está necesariamente en `ggplot()` sino mucho más abajo, en `nls()` y como esta última maneja el parámetro `start`. Veamos un ejemplo más sencillo y que en definitiva es lo que por debajo estaría haciendo `geom_smooth()`:

```
# Renombramos las columnas para que sea consistentes con tu ejemplo
msleep <- rename(msleep, "x" = "sleep_rem", "y" = "sleep_total")

nls(formula = y ~ max_sleep_total * x / (min_sleep_rem + x), 
    data = msleep,
    start = list(max_sleep_total = max(msleep$x, na.rm = TRUE), 
                 min_sleep_rem = min(msleep$y, na.rm = TRUE))
)
```

Esto funciona. Sin embargo, esto:

```
nls(formula = y ~ max_sleep_total * x / (min_sleep_rem + x), 
    data = msleep,
    start = list(max_sleep_total = max(x, na.rm = TRUE), 
                 min_sleep_rem = min(y, na.rm = TRUE))
)

Error in nls(formula = y ~ max_sleep_total * x/(min_sleep_rem + x), data = msleep,  : 
  object 'x' not found
```

no lo hace, el error más inmediato es que no existe el objeto `x`, el mensaje es algo ambiguo, por que puede hacernos suponer que el problema esta en la formula, sin embargo realmente el problema está en el parámetro `start`. Para entender esto, debemos preguntarnos ¿Es válido hacer esto?:

```
l <- list(max_sleep_total = max(x, na.rm = TRUE), 
          min_sleep_rem = min(y, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Claramente no, no importa en el entorno que lo hagamos, a menos que hubiéramos definido de antemano los objetos `x` e  `y` esto no funcionará. Y éste es el problema que tenemos, en `nls()` en un determinado momento es necesario obtener los nombres de cada elemento de esta lista, y se hace: `names(start)` en ese momento se evalúa definitivamente la lista del parámetro `start`,  obviamente falla por lo ya mencionado.

Y, ¿Por que en el caso de la formula si funciona referenciar directamente a las columnas de la data? por que las formulas dentro de `nls()` se evalúan de forma distinta, mediante `eval()` en función de `data`, siempre que se la necesite se hace algo mas o menos parecido a esto: `eval(formula, data, environment(formula))`. De esta forma `x` e  `y` son válidos por que existen en el environment de `data` y `max_sleep_total` y `min_sleep_rem` también por que  eventualmente ya han sido definidos en el "enclosure" (dónde se buscarán los objetos si no estuvieran en `data`) que es el `enviroment` de la formula, es decir el ámbito de la función.

Lo que es razonable preguntar es: ¿por que `geom_smooth` no incorpora la inteligencia para calcular y luego "traducir" los parámetros recibidos a los nombres de objeto `data` con el cual se está trabajando?, tal vez se deba a la idea de los autores, de mantener el parámetro `method.args` los más genérico posible para soportar los distintos algoritmos que se pueden aplicar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Me aclara un par de cosas, 1. no es un problema de Non Standard Evaluation,que en algún momento pensé que sí. 2. `stat_smooth` se maneja de manera muy genérica, como señalas, sólo pasa los argumentos como una lista y el `parent.frame()`.  De hecho creo entender por qué en la fórmula funcionan los nombres asignados en `aes`: el default de `data=` en `nls` es `parent.frame()`, entonces debería estar heredando el entorno de `ggplot()`.

Comment: Sigo sin entender del todo pq `max()` dentro de `start()` evalúa en el entorno global. Por lo que dices es el comportamiento usual en R. Mi idea era que  debería heredar el entorno de la función que lo llama -`nls`-, que a su vez hereda el entorno de `stat_smooth()`. Por la tarde voy a revisar el código de `nls` y actualizo mi pregunta, creo que ahí está el problema. Mirando por arriba vi que se crean varios entornos ahí dentro, pasa que como tiene muchos `if` no sé cuál es exactamente mi caso. Si supiera usar un debbuger sería todo más fácil ;) Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Ahora que lo leo y veo tus comentarios  no me convence hablar de entornos, cuando evaluas `min(y)` en cualquier entorno, afuera o adentro de cualquier función te dará un error, por que efectivamente no existe el objeto `y`, aunque si existe el `msleep$y`, la única forma  sería `eval(substitute(min(y)),msleep)`, en el que se evalúa `y` en función de `msleep`.

Comment: @mpaladino, actualice mi respuesta, no me convence del todo la forma  de explicarlo pero si la idea general.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo Patricio por el tiempo dedicado a la respuesta. Por lo que dices el problema está en que `nls` evalúa de manera diferente a `formula` y  `start`, por eso en un caso encuentra a `y` y en el otro no. Eso responde a la pregunta. Estaba tratando de usar los subsets que ofrece `color=` dentro de `aes()` por simplicidad. Esos funcionan para la fórmula, de hecho se grafican 5 curvas de 5 modelos, pero evidentemente con `nls` no funcionan para calcular parámetros. No sé si hay alguna manera de indicar en la llamada a max() y min() dónde buscar a `y`, pero este es un caso raro.

Comment: @mpaladino, efectivamente, son distintas formas de evaluación, para usar `max()` o `min()` deberías referenciar el data.frame original, por ej. `min(msleep$y)` creo que es la única forma sin tener que reescribir la función. Gracias a tí por la oportunidad de aprender.

Comment: Sí, y por lo que vi del código de `nls` mejor dejarlo como está ;)