# ¿Cómo hacer un gráfico utilizando ggplot2 y 3 variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tengo una tabla llamada datos y en ella tengo las columnas y en ellas tengo las columnas `item_type`(que es un factor), `item_mrp`(que es numerica) y `item_visibility`(que es numerica)

El resultado que quiero se parece mucho a este

En la siguiente imagen se muestra la relacion de la suma de item_visibility e item_mrp, tomando en cuanta los item_type

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un amigo me ayudo con esta duda y lo hizo con los siguientes pasos

1-Se agrupa la data por `item_type`

```
    producto = group_nby(datos, item_type)
```

2- Obtenemos la suma del `item_mrp` y `item_visibilidad` de cada grupo

```
     agrupacion = summarise(producto, visibilidad=sum(item_visibility), 
     mrp=sum(item_mrp))
```

3- graficamos

```
    ggplot()+geom_point(aes(x=agrupacion$visibility, y=agrupacion$mrp, 
      color=agrupacion$item_type, size=6))+ labs(x="visibilidad", 
    y="mrp",     colour="producto")
```

La pregunta seria esta: existe alguna forma de hacer este grafico partiendo desde el paso 3-graficamos, es decir, sin tener k hacer los pasos 1 y 2, utilizando solo los comandos de graficacion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Respuesta corta:

No directamente dentro de la llamada de `ggplot2` porque esta librería no tiene una forma fácil de hacer transformaciones dentro de la llamada al gráfico y eso por buenos motivos.

Sí dentro de una función personalizada que haga tanto la transformación como el gráfico. (ver 3)

## Respuestas largas:

### 1. No es buena idea:

El gráfico lo estás haciendo con `gglot()`, una librería para gráficos basada en un paradigma llamado "gramática de los gráficos" (el `gg` de `gg`plot). Hay varias cosas interesantes en la gramática de los gráficos, una relevante para este tema es que se busca siempre que lo que se ve (los elementos geométricos) tengan un mapeado directo con los datos que le suministramos.

Por eso se trata de evitar que la función que hace el gráfico haga también transformaciones o sumarios. En este caso serían las sumatorias de `item_mrp` e `item_visibilidad`. Desde este paradigma la manipulación de los datos para el gráfico, por convención, se hace aparte.

Al hacer cada paso por separado además tienes la posibilidad de validar cada paso cuando estás trabajando en una sesión interactiva.

Esto tiene más sentido si en lugar de pasar vectores al gráfico (como lo haces con `agrupacion$item_type`) trabajas directamente con el data.frame completo,llamas a las columnas por su nombre y unes los pasos con el operador `%>%`.

### 2. Sería muy difícil

2.1. Una peculiaridad de ggplot dentro de R es que te permite trabajar con nombres de columna desnudos, es decir, llamar a objetos que no están en el entorno global y sin que sean necesarias comillas. Para lograrlo "rompieron" las reglas de evaluación de código estándar de R haciendo algo que se llama NSE o Non Standard Evaluation. En concreto, eso complica hacer operaciones de transformación de datos **dentro** de la llamada de la función `ggplot` porque las demás funciones de R no comprenden este comportamiento y no encuentran los objetos. En este hilo encuentras bastantes un ejemplo de cómo se pueden complicar las cosas haciendo eso:

[¿En qué entorno evalúa `stat_smooth()` la función que ajusta el modelo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/156466/en-qu%C3%A9-entorno-eval%C3%BAa-stat-smooth-la-funci%C3%B3n-que-ajusta-el-modelo)

2.2. La alternativa disponible sería sería crear un `stat` (un tipo de extensiones de ggplot para transformaciones de datos) que haga la transformación que necesitas de una manera general. En tu caso debería hacer la sumatoria de dos columnas numéricas condicionales a un factor. Esto implicaría mucho trabajo y conocimiento profundo del funcionamiento interno de `ggplot`. Sólo valdría la pena si vas a dar solución a un problema general al que te enfrentas muchísimas veces. Digamos, si estás desarrollando una librería.

### 3. Workaround: Una función ad hoc(*)

> No es exactamente lo que querías, pero te permite generar el gráfico con una sola llamada.
>   (*) Actualizado para ggpplot2 3.0

Podrías envolver todo tu código (transformación + gráfico) en una función. Algo así:

```
  grafico_de_barly <- function(datos, factor, numerica1, numerica2) {
    factor <- enquo(factor)
    x <- enquo(numerica1)
    y <- enquo(numerica2)
    datos %>% 
      group_by(!!factor) %>% 
      summarise(x = sum(!!x), y = sum(!!y)) %>% 
      mutate(color = as.factor(!!factor)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, factor, color = color)) + geom_point()
    }

  # Test con mtcars

  grafico <- grafico_de_barly(mtcars, gear, mpg, wt)
  grafico
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que hace todo en un paso, pero perdiendo flexibilidad, ya que se pierden propiedades de los datos tales como nombres. Algunos los podrías arreglar después agregando atributos con el operador `+`. Digamos

```
grafico + labs(x="mpg", y="wt", 
               title="Los autos de los 70 con caja de 5ta eran compactos")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Usando `ggplot2` 3.0

A partir de la versión 3.0 `ggplot2` permite usar las convenciones (y funciones) de evaluación no estándar dentro de las llamadas. Es decir, podemos pasar nombres de columna "programáticamente", sin conocer cómo se van a llamar al momento de escribir la función. Eso resuelve el problema que tenía la solución anterior, que usaba unos nombres fijos de columna (`x` y `y`). Ahora podemos recuperar los nombres de la llamada a la función `grafico_de_barly2` y usarlo para etiquetar los ejes.

```
grafico_de_barly2 <- function(datos, factor, numerica1, numerica2) {  
  # Detiene la ejecución y pasa un error si no está instalado ggplot2 3.0
if (substr(as.character(packageVersion("ggplot2")), 1, 1) <3) {
  stop("Requiere ggplot2 3.0.0 o superior")
} else {
  factor <- enquo(factor)
  x <- enquo(numerica1)
  y <- enquo(numerica2)
  nombre_x <- quo_name(x)
  nombre_y <- quo_name(y)
  datos %>% 
    group_by(!!factor) %>% 
    summarise(!!nombre_x := sum(!!x), !!nombre_y := sum(!!y)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = !!x, y = !!y, factor, color = !!factor)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    theme_minimal()}
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Programar la función es bastante complicado, pero una vez que está hecha es mucho más reutilizable.

Comment: muchas gracias por la sugerencia, la pondre en practica

Comment: Agregué una versión con ggplot2 3.0 que soluciona el problema de los nombres en los ejes.

Comment: muchas gracias por toda la aclaracion, ahora me pongo las pilas